# VBA How make loop for created 2 codes

Tags: excel

i need a loop for created 2 codes (there will be more) . As for now in column O i have 2 conditions/criteria based on which i'm using for filter a table with data. Right now i just made one by one, but in future i want to add to column O more criteria that is why i am asking to make some loop to do all action until all criteria in column O will be finished. As well - how it might look if i want to add next criteria but in column P (so 1st do all in column O, when all criteria are finished go to P etc...)

```
Sub FILTER1st()
'

Sheets("schedule").Select
'
Dim filterValue As Variant

' Copy the value from cell O3
filterValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Range("O3").Value

' Go to the "SOP" sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Activate

' Filter column using the copied value as filter criteria
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue


Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("temp").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    End Sub
```

```
Sub FILTER2nd()
    
Sheets("schedule").Select
'
Dim filterValue As Variant

' Copy the value from cell O4
filterValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Range("O4").Value

' Go to the "SOP" sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Activate

' Filter column using the copied value as filter criteria
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue


Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("temp").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the first thing you want to do is establish which parts of the code are *common* to them both, and which parts are *different*.  And, in your case, the main difference is the `filterValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Range(???).Value` line, and then dumping the Paste at the *end* of your other sheet

This means that the loop will be changing this value, and then rerunning the same code.  We could do this as a single Sub that included the loop, but for Debugging purposes I propose that it will be easier to have two Subs — one that contains your loop of values, and the other that **does something** with that value.

So, this first Sub will loop down Column O, and feed the values into a second Sub called `ApplyMyFilter()`:

```vb
Public Sub FilterControlLoop()
    Dim FilterColumn AS Long: FilterColumn = 15 'Column O is Column 15
    Dim FirstRow As Long: FirstRow = 3 'Start on Row 3 of Column O
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = 4 'Finish on Row 4 of Column O

    Dim CurrentRow As Long

    If FirstRow > Last Row Then 'Make sure they're the right way around!
        CurrentRow = FirstRow
        FirstRow = LastRow
        LastRow = CurrentRow
    End If

    'This is the loop itself
    For CurrentRow = FirstRow To LastRow
        ApplyMyFilter ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Cells(CurrentRow, FilterColumn).Value
    Next CurrentRow
End Sub
```

So, now we just need to break down your Filter code to accept the value it is being passed as an Argument, instead of looking for a hard-coded value.  Also, using `.End(xlDown)` and `.End(xlToRight)` can have issues, if there is only a single row/column involved.  It is much better to do things in reverse, and use `.End(xlUp)` and `.End(xlToLeft)`:

```vb
Private Sub ApplyMyFilter(filterValue AS Variant)

    ' Go to the "SOP" sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Activate

    ' Filter column using the copied value as filter criteria
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue

    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("temp").Select
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

So, that will run your code *as you wrote it*.  But, while I'm here, there are a few inefficiencies to correct, or improvements to make — mostly centring around [How to Avoid Using `Select` in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)

If we run a `Sheet(..).Select`, and then an `ActiveSheet.<DoSomething>` then (**usually**, but not quite *always*) you can just use `Sheet(..).<DoSomething>` instead, without having to change the sheet:

```vb
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue
```

Similarly, the `Range.Copy` method will also accept a `Destination` argument, instead of needing to use the Clipboard and `Paste` it later:

```vb
Selection.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Range("B3")
```

Finally, we can use a `With` constructor to reference a Range with respect to itself, eliminating the need for a `Selection`:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Range("B2")
    Range(.End(xlToRight), .End(xlDown)).Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
End With
```

This lets us reduce the size of your Filter action Sub:

```vb
Private Sub ApplyMyFilter(filterValue AS Variant)
    ' Filter column using the copied value as filter criteria
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Range("A1:Z1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filterValue

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Range("B2")
        Range(.End(xlToRight), .End(xlDown)).Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp").Rows.Count,2).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need to have multiple columns, you can just adjust the Control Loop, to include Nested For Loops over both Column and Row, instead of just Column.

---

You may also want to Clear your "temp" sheet at the start of the Loop Control, with something like:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp")
    Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Similarly, the `With` constructor for the `Copy` could be improved slightly like this:

```vb
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP")
    Range(.Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Copy _
```

Or, even just using the Programmatic Object Name of the sheet instead of needing `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP")` and `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("temp")`; I, personally, find `sheet1.Activate` to be much neater than `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOP").Activate`

Comment: Hello @Chronocidal , first of all - huge thanks for so fast answer :) As for now all works. I have just one question about Last Row - how to adjust code if i don't know which row will be final (let's say once it will be 4th, once it will be 10th row in Column O) - how make it to works till last value in column O without specifying fixed value ?

Comment: @nozu1984 You can use `.End(..)` to find the cell, and `.Row` to return which row it is, e.g. `LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("schedule").Rows.Count, FilterColumn).End(xlUp).Row`